# Why datagrid doesn't show data in rows

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

My datagrid doesn't show data in rows despite that I added data.
Car is list of id of cars.

```
 DataGridTextColumn col1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
 myDataGrid.Columns.Add(col1);
 col1.Binding = new Binding("id");
 col1.Header = "ID";
 foreach (Car carr in car)
 {
     myDataGrid.Items.Add(carr.ToString());
 }
```

My xaml file

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Height="300" 
          Width="600"
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          IsReadOnly="True" 
          RenderTransformOrigin="0.52,0.47" 
          Margin="100,82,0,0" 
          FontSize="15" />
```

Comment: Unless you made an override for `ToString`, `carr.ToString()` is not going to give you the `id`, it will give you the class name. I don't ever bind this way in WPF, I prefer MVVM, but it appears you have attempted to bind data AND also add items manually. You should pick one way, preferably binding by setting the grid's DataContext.

Comment: I override method ToString() in Car class that it returns
`return "id=" + id;`

Comment: Ok, at least there's that but the binding is doing nothing. Just because you have converted the id to string doesn't mean the binding is smart enough to know that or even that the data came from a `Car` in the first place. Try what Dmitri said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the ItemSource property of the DataGrid:

```
    myDataGrid.ItemSource = car;
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid?view=netframework-4.8

for more information.

***OR***
You can use xaml for custom columns:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="CARS" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Car}" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Path=IdPropertyOfCarObject}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

And in code behind set the data context to the class that has a list of car objects.

Comment: I tried this way but I still get DataGrid with two rows which are blank

Comment: @Trev0N try setting `AutoGenerateColumns` to True on the grid.

Comment: @Trev0N have you used it with col1.Binding = new Binding() or just by itself?

Comment: @DmitriCaragheaur just by itself

Comment: @Trev0N I update my answer with an alternative way using xaml